# Android Studio : Failed to resolve <github dependency>

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Let me first start of by saying that I just recently migrated to Android Studio and being totally honest I didn't like it. Now there is this git I am trying to import into my project - https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator
Although the compile statement which the owner has asked to put creates the error. 
I added it into the dependency{} in my build.gradle file.

```
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.5@aar'
```

> Failed to resolve: me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.5@aar

Comment: Is there any prerequisite repository I need to add for the program to access github ?

Comment: This imports properly for me - what is the repository that you're using? You can generally find it in your root `build.gradle`, not in the one that is inside of your `/app` folder.

Comment: I tried finding the second gradle from the root, but I am unable to do so. There is just one *.gradle file which is build.gradle and it is right inside the app folder. It has the mavenCentral() repository inside the repositories{}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably had forgotten this line under your gradle :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Edit the root gradle located in root/build.gradle**

I'll just explain a little :

When you add this line : compile 'repository or jar url', it prompts your gradle that it should find the repository (or the jar) and add it to your source.

But where should it search for this particular repository ? That is the purpose of this line, to declare a location from where the gradle should search from. In most of the cases it is - jcenter 
([see this link](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter))

Comment: Looks like adding this made the gradle run without errors. Now just have to check whether the library was added or not. Thanks mate.

Comment: Basically, when you create a project, this line is automatically created (cause when you want to compile a project, gradle has to know where the project it and most of the time he's under jcenter, see https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter)

Comment: I am using a rather old version of Android Studio. Update is almost done. I am guessing this wont happen in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just open build.gradle(Module:app) and copy pase on your dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.5@aar'
}
```

Comment: if it says "Failed to resolve: me.relex:circle:indicator:1.1.5@aar" it's because he have added this line...

Comment: I did pretty much the same thing and have explained it in the question too. The one who gave the answer cleared my doubts about Android Studio, check it out.